# How to redirect after login, the working way?

Tags: redirect, login, buddypress

I've tried everything: [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/), [Redirection](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/), some unworking javascript hacks, [routemap PHP Class](http://dev.horde.org/routes/) (which is really impressive, but I'm not sure that's very useful in this case).

I'm using [Theme My Login](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/), but its redirection settings just wouldn't respond. (Still need it, though).

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be because of a plugin incompatibility. I found that I couldn't get the redirection feature to work when I had the plugin "bbPress" activated. Deactivate all the rest of your plugins, then activate them one by one to determine the culprit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the WordPress function `wp_redirect()`. If you want a redirect after login or logout, check the plugin Adminimize, it has an option for this.

Two examples for a redirect in a custom plugin or `functions.php` of the theme (the following example uses the variable `$pagenow`):

```
function fb_redirect_1() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'plugins.php' === $pagenow ) {
        if ( function_exists('admin_url') ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('edit-comments.php') );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/' . 'edit-comments.php' );
        }
    }
}
if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fb_redirect_1' );
```

An alternative with `$_server`, checks the URL too:

```
function fb_redirect_2() {

    if ( preg_match('#wp-admin/?(index.php)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
        if ( function_exists('admin_url') ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('edit-comments.php') );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/' . 'edit-comments.php' );
        }
    }
}
if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fb_redirect_2' );
```

Comment: Yep. Finally ended up with something just like this. Thanks a lot!